# Android cursor charc to array

Tags: android

I hope i explain the correctly...

What i want to do is be able to run a query and then get the first record of that query and put the characters into an character array, then i want to get the second query and put that into the same array depending on where it is suppose to be inserted into the array.

So for example...the first record from the query will have the string 'hello', i want this to be inserted into the array at position one. Then i want record two which will be 'you' to be inserted at position 6. so when the character array is out put it will display 'hello you'

How do i go about doing this?

```
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbs.getReadableDatabase();
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Table"; 
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null); 
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        char charac_array[];
        charac_array = new char[10];
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                ???       
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not really put correctly. What do you want? An array of chars or an array of strings? Only from your words "at position 6" I assume you want a character array, but what you got there is a string array - with length 10? WHY? If you want all strings in one, simply concatenate them! Please work on your question and but the right tags to it. This is *not* an Android question at all!

Comment: Yeh i would like a character array sorry, i am string to build a text from a table, but the words and things to be printed out can be changed in the table, the document that the words are going to be printed out to is only 10 characters long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you probably want:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String s = cursor.getString(...);
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    sb.append(s);
}
String helloYou = sb.toString();
```

**UPDATE**

To fill a char array from String

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] charArray = new char[10];
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    String s = getFromCursor(c);
    s.getChars(0, 10, charArray, 0); // <-- this copies 10 chars from s to charArray
    sb.append(charArray);
}
```

You'll have to take care when s is less than 10 characters though.

Comment: i dont want to add it to the string builder until i complete each full charc_array

Comment: Do you need only 10 chars from every string which you get from the table? Then you can change `sb.append(s)` to `sb.append(s.substring(0,10))`...

Comment: I need to fill the char array, and then add it to the string builder, im not sure if i am explaining it correctly

Comment: I don't understand why you have to fill the char array, but anyway, please see my answer updated :)